# Can a web browser/client serve as a sql client, for example using URI scheme?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm not expecting code examples from any server side technology, sorry for that, I have some doubts, therefore let's take the example of `file_get_contents`.

Is: `file_get_contents("mysql://user@localhost:3306/db");` possible, for example in PHP ?

Is `mysql://` a valid URI scheme in PHP ?

Is there any alternative (it does not seem secure but still) to achieve this from a web browser or client/socket without actually using a whole php file ?

Comment: No. No. A whole PHP file?

Comment: By saying the above I meant visiting site.com/client.php, the php file serving as a mysql client. I do not want that. I am searching a way to achieve a mysql connection from an http client.

Comment: What is it that you're trying to achieve? You can only (or rather, "should" only) interact with MySQL via SQL commands. If you need to get the contents of a DB, use something like `mysqldump`.